# How to rid of Save As dialog and yellow box in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

When I generate and save a document with a link in it using TCPDF. It is always showing a save as dialog before closing in the pdf reader.

```
"Do you want to save the changes to file.pdf before closing?"
```

Also there is a yellow note box in the chrome browser when I hover over the link... as shown in the image below.

My code with problem is like this.

```
$pdf->writeHTML('<a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=system_view_data&id=1">link</a>');
```

However, if my links are empty in my html then there is no problem while closing the pdf, also then there is no yellow box anymore in links. The following code for example is working fine.

```
$pdf->writeHTML('<a href="">link</a>');
```

Here is a complete example to reproduce the problem.

```
require_once __DIR__.'../../external_classes/TCPDF/tcpdf.php';
    $pdf = new \TCPDF();
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('ABC');
    $pdf->SetTitle('ABC');
    $pdf->SetSubject('ABC');

    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, "ABC", "ABC");
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 10, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML('<a href="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=system_view_data&id=1">link</a>');
    ob_clean();
    $pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'D');
```

The above example will generate the output like the following image. Which will have both the problems, I have tested both on tcpdf version 5.9.x and 6.2.x.

[image]

Comment: What reader are you using, Chrome built-in one? Does it happen with other readers such as Adobe's?

Comment: happening in all readers. The yellow box is chrome specific.

Comment: Same was asked in this link... https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/aadcc3b4/?limit=25
The same problem cause an issue while closing the docs in at least adobe readers.

Comment: On a side note, inserting a relative URL in a PDF document does not probably make any sense. You may want to add the missing protocol prefix and host name.

Comment: Of-course I had that... just removed it for the purpose of example.

Comment: I've even upgraded my local copy of TCPDF to the latest version but I can by no means reproduce it. You should create a simple test case (which I suspect you don't have yet) and, probably, the issue will reveal itself while do you do it. You should also share the resulting PDF document with other co-workers in order to discard problems with your own PC (such as a virus that spreads through PDF files).

Comment: Kindly check I have added a live example and code to reproduce the problem. I have spent a lot of time to format the pdf and now client is bothered with these two little problems.

Comment: Your new sample code does not reproduce the issue here (TCPDF/6.2.12). Your live link does. However, they're clearly not the same code. As I said, if you make a copy of your current live code and start removing code until the issue stops happening, you'll possibly get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135567/discussion-between-waqas-bukhary-and-alvaro-gonzalez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found some explanation to both the problems.

**1. First Problem: The issue of Save as Dialog**

For some reason the tcpdf library is appending my website html at the end of the pdf. I found this out by viewing my pdf in pure text using a text editor.

Using an exist function immediately after output() will fix it.

```
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'D');
exit();
```

**2. Second Problem: The issue of yellow link box in chrome**

This is currently an unresolved active issue in chrome. Check this [link](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/283) for example on mPdf forum.

Answer (score 1):

You may resolve the second problem by removing annotations at all.

- Create your own class MyTCPDF extends \TCPDF.
- Copy to created class "protected function _putannotsobjs()" from tcpdf.php. You will override it.
- Change this string in method form 
  `` `$annots .= ' /Contents ' . $this->_textstring($pl['txt'], $annot_obj_id);` ``

  enter code here
  to
  `` `$annots .= ' /Contents ()';` ``
- Use your class for generation pdf file.
- You may put any logic in this method an disable annotations by constant or something else.